# String.split and counting tokens

Tags: java, regex, string, split, token

Can someone explain to me why the output is the same for this two?
//S means non-whitespace. Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String test = "I am noob ";
    String[] tokens = test.split("\\S");
    System.out.println(tokens.length);

    String test2 = "I am noob 132434";
    String[] tokens2 = test2.split("\\S");
    System.out.println(tokens2.length);
}
```

Comment: change it to small \\s and you will know the difference

Comment: because java removes some empty strings.

Comment: probably because of the last space in this String: String test = "I am noob ";

Comment: In your case, `132434` is treated as a trailing *separator*, so it gets removed.